# How can i replace a code within my pandas dataframe with a dict mapping?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a table like below:

```
Group col1      col2       col3
A     shop_101  shop_102   shop_104
B     shop_101  shop_105   shop_108
C     shop_101  shop_103   shop_109
C     shop_111  shop_122   shop_104
```

I also have a dict which has mappings of these e.g.:

```
{'group_name': {103: 'AUTO',
  104: 'BUSINESS',
  105: 'STORES',
  106: 'DIRECT MARKETING',
  107: 'DISCOUNT STORES',
  108: 'PHARMACIES',
  109: 'GOVERNMENT',
  110: 'ELECTRONICS',
  112: 'FOOD & GROCERY',
  113: 'FUEL',
  114: 'GENERAL RETAIL GOODS',
  116: 'HEALTH',
  124: 'Tfl'}}
```

how can i replace all instances of the code in the dataframe with this mapping from dict?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) for substrings replacement values of dict with convert keys to strings:

```
d = {'group_name': {103: 'AUTO',
  104: 'BUSINESS',
  105: 'STORES',
  106: 'DIRECT MARKETING',
  107: 'DISCOUNT STORES',
  108: 'PHARMACIES',
  109: 'GOVERNMENT',
  110: 'ELECTRONICS',
  112: 'FOOD & GROCERY',
  113: 'FUEL',
  114: 'GENERAL RETAIL GOODS',
  116: 'HEALTH',
  124: 'Tfl'}}


d1 = {str(k):v for k, v in d['group_name'].items()}
df = df.replace(d1, regex=True)
print (df)
  Group      col1         col2             col3
0     A  shop_101     shop_102    shop_BUSINESS
1     B  shop_101  shop_STORES  shop_PHARMACIES
2     C  shop_101    shop_AUTO  shop_GOVERNMENT
3     C  shop_111     shop_122    shop_BUSINESS
```

If need specify columns for replacement:

```
cols = ['col1','col2','col3']
d1 = {str(k):v for k, v in d['group_name'].items()}
df[cols] = df[cols].replace(d1, regex=True)
print (df)
  Group      col1         col2             col3
0     A  shop_101     shop_102    shop_BUSINESS
1     B  shop_101  shop_STORES  shop_PHARMACIES
2     C  shop_101    shop_AUTO  shop_GOVERNMENT
3     C  shop_111     shop_122    shop_BUSINESS
```